# Managing OpenCV python Cmake Studio Windows

Tags: python, visual-studio, opencv, cmake, cmake-gui

Recently ,  I wanted to install OpenCV (in Win10 64 bit ) using Cmake 3.5.0-rc3 and Visual studio 2015 . I have python 3.5 as root and 2.7 as python2 . The issue is while configuring it recognizes python 3.5 as main interpreter but i want  it to be 2.7.Is there a possible way to make cmake recognize 2.7 as my main python while maintaining python 3,5 in my PC . I can probably do it by deleting python 3.5 but i dont want that . Help is very much appreciated.Thanking you ,

P.S. If there is a simpler way to install OpenCV along with extramodules in WIndows ,please do tell me  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should look for Python related variables in the CMake GUI. There may be some variables you could set to force paths to the python2.7 interpreter, libs and include dirs.